# Actionscript - how to check if text is too long for dynamic text box?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dynamic, actionscript, multiline

I have a simple dynamic text field which is multi-line and center aligned in flash file. This field can have a variable width.
I put some dynamic text inside this when running program. How can I check if the text is too long for the first line and has been moved to the second line in the text field using actionscript?

Ex.
This is some text
vs
This is some
text

Basically I need to move the text box up or down based on if its multi-line

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the width of 'TextField fixed.

Also make sure the textfield is multiLine  like so:

```
 var tf:TextField = new TextField();
 tf.multiline = true;
```

Then, you can check number of lines of that textfield like so:

```
 if(tf.numLines >1)
 {
     //Move text UP or Down here
 }else
 {
     //Move text UP or Down here
 }
```

If number of lines is greater than 1, then move the text box UP/DOWN according to your need.